# Basic probability: if p(¬X) ≤ a certain value is p(X) going to be ≥ that value?

Tags: probability

I think the answer is yes and that this has do with the addition theorem, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Note that $\Pr(X)+\Pr(\neg X) = 1$

Comment: NO.  If $P(X) \le 0.9$ is follows that $P(\neg X) \ge 0.1$.  Not the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noting that $\Pr(X)=1-\Pr(\neg X)$ by the law of total probability, after some simple algebraic manipulation we find the correct inequality is that

$$\Pr(X)\leq k\implies \Pr(\neg X)\geq 1-k$$